# ArcSDESQLExecute is not able to handle unique identifiers

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5 I found that ArcSDESQLExecute is not able to handle [unique identifiers](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) a.k.a GUIDS, in a table.

I tried to run the following Script:

```
database = 'C:\\Installation\\updm.sde'

egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(database)
# Getting the ID's froma table
sql_clause = "SELECT PROJECT_ID from DataOwner.My_PROJECTS;"

query_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql_clause)

# Whatever operation you want to do with the results, in this case
# is just the verification of how many results, but they will be 
# iterated later

len(query_return)
```

the table My_PROJECTS has a column PROJECT_ID defined as a uniqueidentifier., the result of the execution is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [39]:
Line 12:    query_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql_clause)

File C:\ArcGISPro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py, in execute:
Line 44:    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.Execute(*gp_fixargs(args)))

AttributeError: ArcSDESQLExecute: StreamBindOutputColumn ArcSDE Error -65 Invalid pointer argument to function
```

Is there any way to solve this?

**EDIT:**
Removed the line from the code that was just noise

**EDIT 2:**
Added clarification on the code, and clarification of the type of column

Comment: Only use supported data types? Cast unsupported types to supported ones?

Comment: The current documentation does not list the supported types

Comment: Of course it does. Located by a google on "ArcGIS SQL Server supported datatypes" -- https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/manage-sql-server/data-types-sqlserver.htm

Comment: @Vince I mean the documentation of the tool [link]https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm . Taking into account the documentation you show, the uniqueidentifier is supported.

Comment: The -65 bind error usually means the column is unsupported, though the extra semicolon seems to have just thrown it off. BLOB/CLOB/NCLOB columns have a history of errors, plus geometry columns are not supported in native SQL cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the suggestion of @Vince, and **despite the fact that unique identifiers are supported**, I went for a casting approach

```
database = 'C:\\Installation\\updm.sde'

egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(database)
# Getting the ID's froma table
sql_clause = "SELECT CAST(PROJECT_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) from DataOwner.My_PROJECTS;"

query_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql_clause)

# Whatever operation you want to do with the results, in this case
# is just the verification of how many results, but they will be 
# iterated later

len(query_return)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the select (a count or rows, all the ids). This is probably just a code snippet but sql_query is not declared. Also if you are trying to return an int I don't believe len will work.

I did some of my own testing and used a where clause, and dropped the semi-colon with your code and it worked.

sql_clause = "SELECT PROJECT_ID from DataOwner.My_PROJECTS WHERE PROJECT_ID > 0"

Comment: In your own testing, could you use a column set as UNIQUEIDENFIER instead if an INT